# Прогресс бар поделить на 3 этапа

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, progress-bar

Можно ли реализовать такой прогресс бар:

[image: Скриншот прогресс бара]

Если у кого нибудь есть сниппет данного скрипта, поделитесь пожалуйста. Прогресс бар делиться на с этапа. Работает как обычный от 0% до 100%

Comment: А что вы пытались сделать?

Comment: Я даже в голове представить не могу, как это реализуется. По этому хочу получить опыт если он у кого нибудь есть

Comment: можно на svg это сделать можно на html + css - на svg проще так как писать меньше

Comment: Можно svg маской, нижний объект - полоска, сверху маска

Comment: Хорошая идея. Спасибо большое

Comment: кто то минусит - я исправил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не нужен никакой яваскрипт, достаточно CSS-градиента.

Вот (в переменную `--gap` я записал ширину промежутка между этапами для удобства изменения):

```js
let root = document.documentElement;

function changeProgress() {
  root.style.setProperty('--color2', "var(--completedStageColor)");
}
```

```css
:root {
--gap: 20px;
--completedStageColor: navy;
--futureStageColor: #70B2D4;
--color1: var(--completedStageColor);
--color2: var(--futureStageColor);
--color3: var(--futureStageColor)
}


.prorgress {
  display:inline-block;
  width:400px;
  height:20px;
  background-image:linear-gradient(to right, 
    var(--color1) 0%, 
    var(--color1) calc((100% - var(--gap) * 2) / 3), 
      transparent calc((100% - var(--gap) * 2) / 3), 
      transparent calc((100% - var(--gap) * 2) / 3 + var(--gap)), 
    var(--color2) calc((100% - var(--gap) * 2) / 3 + var(--gap)), 
    var(--color2) calc((100% - var(--gap) * 2) / 3 * 2 + var(--gap)), 
      transparent calc((100% - var(--gap) * 2) / 3 * 2 + var(--gap)), 
      transparent calc((100% - var(--gap) * 2) / 3 * 2 + var(--gap) * 2), 
    var(--color3) calc((100% - var(--gap) * 2) / 3 * 2 + var(--gap) * 2),
    var(--color3) 100%
  );
}
```

```html
0% <div class="prorgress"></div> 100%<br><br>

<button onclick="changeProgress();">change progress</button>
```

Comment: А как без js выставить, насколько заполнен прогресс-бар?

Comment: Ну, автор писал, что "Работает как обычный от 0% до 100%" и я предположил, что вопрос был в дизайне. Скриптом можно делать перерасчет градиента, или, что проще, задавать цвета переменным типа `--color1`, отвечающим за цвет определенного этапа.

Comment: Приделал кнопку, изменяющую прогресс-бар. Функцию, конечно, нужно расширить, чтобы отображать нужные стадии как надо, это несложный скриптик, но это уж пусть автор делает =)

Comment: Интересное решение! Как скургление сделать? Если должен быть плавный прогрессбар то как сделать?

Comment: обычное  скругление с краев - через бордер-радиус. если каждого этапа, то да, придется насиловать мозг с SVG/masks. Плавность анимации можно, думаю, задать, но тогда скриптом придется не цвет менять, а его положение в градиенте.

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 1):

Пример svg с маской и плавным движением прогрессбара

В примере вместо `animate` должен работать js скрипт загрузки

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 487 64" style="enable-background:new 0 0 487 64;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{clip-path:url(#mask);}
    .st1{fill:none;stroke:#00A99D;stroke-width:37;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st2{fill:none;stroke:#29ABE2;stroke-width:37;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
</style>
<g>
    <defs>
        <path id="SVGID_1_" d="M162,34L162,34c0,9.9-8.1,18-18,18H42c-9.9,0-18-8.1-18-18v0c0-9.9,8.1-18,18-18h102
            C153.9,16,162,24.1,162,34z M299,16H197c-9.9,0-18,8.1-18,18v0c0,9.9,8.1,18,18,18h102c9.9,0,18-8.1,18-18v0
            C317,24.1,308.9,16,299,16z M454,16H352c-9.9,0-18,8.1-18,18v0c0,9.9,8.1,18,18,18h102c9.9,0,18-8.1,18-18v0
            C472,24.1,463.9,16,454,16z"/>
    </defs>
    <clipPath id="mask">
        <use xlink:href="#SVGID_1_"  style="overflow:visible;"/>
    </clipPath>
    <g class="st0">
        <line class="st1" x1="-6.5" y1="34.5" x2="495.5" y2="34.5"/>
    </g>
    <g class="st0">
        <line class="st2" x1="-6.5" y1="34.5" x2="0" y2="34.5">
      <animate attributeName="x2" from="0" to="495.5" begin="1s" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
    </line>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```